# QTP not identifying java objects

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

Quick Test Professional 11.00
Version 11.00.0.0 Build: 1018

Not identifying java objects.
when spy is been used on the java window it identifies it just as a 'window'.

So, is it some issue with the QTP or in the script?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't have the Java Add-in enabled for this script.  It pops up on launching QTP/UFT to allow you to select which add ins should be loaded (unless you deselected the "Show on startup" checkbox on the popup.

You can check if it's enabled by looking in the File-->Settings-->Test Properties at the associated addins.  If it's not there, click the Modify button to add it and then reload QTP to have the addin loaded as well.

Comment: Additionally, make sure open the Java application AFTER opening QTP first.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set a different JAVA_HOME for your Application. (To avoid using same
   JAVA_HOME for UFT and Application. Ideally this should not cause any
   issue. Anyway for safer side.)
2. Ensure you don't have Loadrunner
   Vugen/Loadgen installed in the machine. (Known issue)
3. Launch UFT first and then open the application.
4. Ensure Java add-in is selected in the UFT.